# python 3 select just the integer from a list with strings

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, integer

I have a problem related to Python 3:

I get a list that contains `[b'1']`

The integer is a variable (sometimes 1, sometimes 5,sometimes 938, etc).

I just want to get the integer out of the list.

How do I do this?

Comment: More information is needed about the remaining list members to answer completely. What are you trying to distinguish integers from?

Answer (score 0):

For `a = [b'1']`, then do:

```
x = int(a[0])
```

or with decode from binary string to str first (assuming ASCII), do:

```
x = int(a[0].decode('ascii'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [b'1', b'2', b'abc']
>>> n = [int(elem) for elem in l if elem.isdigit()]
>>> print n
[1, 2]
```

*edit*: Huh, you're right; it breaks with negative values in the strings. A more longhand approach would be:

```
>>> n = []
>>> for elem in l:
...     try:
...             n.append(int(elem))
...     except ValueError:
...             pass
... 
>>> n
[1, 2]
```

Comment: It's not just about negatives - `isdigit()` does not in any way imply that the value can have an integer made out of it (⑦ and other unicode characters will return `true` for `isdigit()`. Ask for forgiveness, not permission.

Comment: @Lattyware: Well, for `bytes` it's just 0-9, per [`_Py_ctype_table`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/04f714765c13/Python/pyctype.c). But yeah.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to just try converting to int. You need to use a helper function, since you can't handle exceptions inside the list comprehension. This works for positive and negative integers

```
def try_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

new_list = [try_int(item) for item in old_list]
```

This technique is known as [EAFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAFP#Exceptions) (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission)

Comment: That will give him a list like `[1, 2, b'abc', -3]`, though. But, depends on what he does with it I guess.